# Как вывести необходимые значения в цикле php?

Tags: php

Представленный ниже код выводит все ключ-значения, как вывести 2 необходимых мне значения, которые соответствуют label?

```
<?php if(  $infos ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $infos as $key => $info ) : ?>
        <?php if( trim($info['value'])) : ?>
            <li class="property-label-<?php echo $key; ?>"><span><?php echo $info['label']; ?> :</span>  <?php echo apply_filters( 'opalestate_'.$key.'_unit_format',  trim($info['value']) ); ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;  ?>
```

Comment: А чему равен label ?

Comment: @Sultanov Shamil, там много разных значений, но мне нужны areasize и floor, то есть как-то нужно написать код чтоб там были эти два значения

Comment: `$info['label']['floor']` и т..д. в чём проблема?

Comment: вообще не понимаю, как подобный код читать можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто добавить список ключей которые нужно выводить и проверять есть ли они в списке.

```
<?php $needle = Array('areasize', 'floor');?>
<?php if(  $infos ): ?>
<?php foreach( $infos as $key => $info ) : ?>
    <?php if( trim($info['value']) && in_array($key, $needle)) : ?>
        <li class="property-label-<?php echo $key; ?>"><span><?php echo $info['label']; ?> :</span>  <?php echo apply_filters( 'opalestate_'.$key.'_unit_format',  trim($info['value']) ); ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
<?php if (!empty($infos['areasize'])):?>
    <li class="property-label-areasize"><span><?php echo $infos['areasize']['label']; ?> :</span>  <?php echo apply_filters( 'opalestate_areasize_unit_format',  trim($infos['areasize']['value']) ); ?></li>
<?endif;?>
<?php if (!empty($infos['floor'])):?>
    <li class="property-label-floor"><span><?php echo $infos['floor']['label']; ?> :</span>  <?php echo apply_filters( 'opalestate_floor_unit_format',  trim($infos['floor']['value']) ); ?></li>
<?endif;?>
```

Comment: у вас при ответе не появилось никакого желания улучшить код? например, использовать короткие открывающие тэги `<?` и закрыть тэг только там где блок php кода заканчивается, а не в каждой строке это делать. Использовать  не `<?php echo`, а `<?=`. Использовать короткий синтаксис объявления массивов `[]`. зы: `needle` в переводе _иголка_ вот обычно ищут иголку (в _стоге сена_ `haystack`), а в вас наоборот. Именуйте переменные корректно.

Comment: как без цикла сделать вывод список из 2ух li:
- label c areasize и его значение;
- label с floor и его значение. Я очень плох в php

Comment: Переменную действительно неправильно назвал, но вот короткая запись тегов php... не факт что у автора вопроса включено short_open_tag

Comment: Спасибо большое, все понятно и работает!